# AngularJS & Jasmine - spyOn async service problems

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I'm trying to unit test a controller which gets some translated strings through an async service, but I'm missing something on Jasmine vs Promises...

Let's start with the error, which is:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'i18n.get('navigation').then')
```

**The testcase**

```
  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new()
  }))

  it('should invoke the i18n service for translations', inject(function ($controller, i18n) {

    spyOn(i18n, 'get')
    var HeaderCtrl = $controller('HeaderCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      i18n: i18n
    })

    expect(i18n.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('navigation')

  }))
```

**The controller**

```
  .controller('HeaderCtrl', function ($scope, i18n) {

    // removing the '.then' part makes the test pass,
    // which makes me almost sure that my missing is in the promise mamnagement
    i18n.get('navigation').then(
      function (data) {
        $scope.strings = data
      },
      function (err) {
        console.log(err)
      })
```

**The async service**

```
      get: function (key) {
        var deferred = $q.defer()

        $http.get('locale/en.json')
          .success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data[key])
          })
          .error(function (err, status) {
            deferred.reject(err, status)
          })

        return deferred.promise
      }
```

I also tried adding some `$http` mocking, but to no avail

**Test with $http mocks**

```
  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $httpBackend) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new()

    $httpBackend.whenGET('locale/en.json')
      .respond(enStrings)
  }))

  it('should invoke the i18n service for translations', inject(function ($controller, i18n) {

    spyOn(i18n, 'get')
    var HeaderCtrl = $controller('HeaderCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      i18n: i18n
    })
    $httpBackend.flush()

    expect(i18n.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('navigation')

  }))
```

Comment: @PSL No luck. Same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally wrapped my head around this.
Hopefully, this answer will be of help to someone else.

All I needed was a mocked promise to return instead of the real one:

```
  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new()
  }))

  it('should invoke the i18n service for translations', inject(function ($controller, i18n) {

    var fakePromise = function () {
      return {
        then: function (ok, err) {},
        success: function (ok) {},
        error: function (err) {}
      }
    }

    // when i18n.get('navigation') gets called, return my fake promise
    spyOn(i18n, 'get').andCallFake(fakePromise)

    var HeaderCtrl = $controller('HeaderCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      i18n: i18n
    })

    expect(i18n.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('navigation')

  }))
```